# How to use JMSSerializer with symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jsonresponse, symfony-4.2

i am building an Api with symfony 4.2 and want to use jms-serializer to serialize my data in Json format, after installing it with

> composer require jms/serializer-bundle

and when i try to use it this way :

````
``` demands = $demandRepo->findAll();
    return $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($demands,'json');```
````

it gives me this errur :

`Service "serializer" not found, the container inside "App\Controller\DemandController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router" and "session" services. Try using dependency injection instead.`

Comment: Off topic. Why do you want to use JMSSerializer instead the default serializer of Symfony? Btw, exec php /bin/console debug:container and check if the service is there. For other part, the best practice is inject the serializer by the constructor.

Comment: the reason of not using Symfony serializer is: that it tired me with the dependencies of the object :'(.
i ll try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you could use the default serializer of Symfony and use it injecting it by the constructor.

```
//...

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

//...

class whatever 
{
    private $serializer;

    public function __constructor(SerializerInterface $serialzer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function exampleFunction()
    {
        //...
        $data = $this->serializer->serialize($demands, "json");
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer problem about JMS serializer...

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer using the Symfony serializer 
it's very easy:

- first : istall symfony serialzer using the command:

> composer require symfony/serializer

- second : using the serializerInterface:

```js
.....//

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

// .....

.... //

 /**
     * @Route("/demand", name="demand")
     */
    public function index(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $demands = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Demand::class)
            ->findAll();

        if($demands){
            return new JsonResponse(
                $serializer->serialize($demands, 'json'),
                200,
                [],
                true
            );
        }else{
            return '["message":"ooooops"]';
        }

    }
    
    //......
```

and with it, i don't find any problems with dependencies or DateTime or other problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have an entity called `Foo.php` that has `id`, `name` and `description`

And you would like to return only `id`, and `name` when consuming a particular API such as `foo/summary/` in another situation need to return `description` as well `foo/details`

here's serializer is really helpful.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/*
* @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Foo {
    /**
    * @Serializer\Groups({"summary", "details"})
    * @Serializer\Expose()
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @Serializer\Groups({"summary"})
    * @Serializer\Expose()
    */
    private $title;

    /**
    * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
    * @Serializer\Expose()
    */
    private $description;

}
```

let's use serializer to get data depends on the group

```
class FooController {
    public function summary(Foo $foo, SerializerInterface $serialzer)
    {
        $context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups('summary');
        $data = $serialzer->serialize($foo, json, $context);

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }

    public function details(Foo $foo, SerializerInterface $serialzer)
    {
        $context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups('details');
        $data = $serialzer->serialize($foo, json, $context);

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```